# Android Studio Emulator issues - HAXM, VT-x

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I'm trying to develop an Android app with Android Studio (running on Windows 8.1 Pro) but I can't get the emulator to work, and don't want to faff around trying to load each iteration of my app onto my phone.

The error I get when I try to start the emulator (Nexus 5, Android 7.0 x86, all emulator images are downloaded and installed): [image: http://puu.sh/rHjgJ/f2d0001076.png]

I have verified that VT-x is enabled in my BIOS. On top of that I have no idea why it tells me anything in regards to a linux distro; as I mentioned above I'm running this on Windows 8.1.

I have also verified Intel Virtualization Technology is enabled in the BIOS.

What is the path where I can verify if /dev/kvm exists or not?

Or, more importantly, how can I get this retched thing to work?

Other things I've tried:

- Manually installing intel HAXM (6.0.4) which gives me the following error:
  [image]
- Re-installing via the Android Studio SDK manager (same error as manually installing)

Any suggestions?

Comment: possibly off-topic, but it is easy to load on your phone.

Comment: I forgot about this thread, I've figured it out. I'll post an answer to this soon.

Comment: are you running as admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out, although I still can't get a faster x86 emulator to run.

I tried creating a new virtual device from scratch using the external AVD manager, but even after downloading the ARM 64 v8a System Image through the external SDK manager, I couldn't get my custom virtual device to work.

What did work is opening Android Studio's built-in AVD manager (the AVD Manager button on the top tool-bar), which prompted me to download the system image for that virtual device (right next to the Play/Start button for that device).
Once that downloaded and extracted, I could successfully start the virtual device and my emulator works.

It's a little sluggish and I bet if I could get the "proper" x86 emulator that Android Studio recommends using it would be more snappy, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

After downloading the sys image, the ADV still did not work with error:

> /dev/kvm is not found

When I reinstalled the HAXM manually, I recieved the same error:

> Failed to configure driver: unknown error. Failed to open driver

I found a [solution on the Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/android-applications-on-intel-architecture/topic/537144#comment-1846715), it works for me, the emulator is ok now.

See below for the relevant excerpt of the above link

```
I. Preparing---------------------------------------------------------
(Optional: check or change your BIOS settings for Intel VT, disable hyper-v, ... as mentioned in other answers.)
1. download and extract the file to a folder
2. cmd -> sfc /SCANNOW
3. reboot
4. cmd -> Bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
5. reboot
II. Installation-----------------------------------------------------
1. start install-android.exe in the folder of the extracted file and install
1.1 if you don't get an error the previous steps have handled the error - continue to III.
1.2 if you get an error DO NOT click OK when the error occurs
3. go to C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM and copy all files, except *.tmp to a new folder
4. then continue/finish the setup (click OK and finish)
5. copy the files from the new folder to C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM and delete *.tmp
6. go to C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM, right-click on the inf-file and choose install
a window with driverinstallation should appear. install driver. it should says ok then..
hint: this is what made the difference for me!
Starting "HaxInst64.exe /i intelhaxm.inf 1" as well as with parameter 4 in the console did
not pop up the driverinstallation-window
III. Test------------------------------------------------------------
1. cmd -> sc query intelhaxm
it should show the service
2. reboot
3. cmd -> sc query intelhaxm
it should says service running..
IV. Reset------------------------------------------------------------
1. cmd -> Bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
2. reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

your system is running on Windows 8.1 Pro please enable Intel virtualization Technology in BIOS please follow steps

**[For More Information And Example](http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios)**

Comment: Already have, sorry, I forgot to mention it in my OP. Edited OP to reflect that.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: Did you not read my post? I have tried manually installing from that link and also tried installing via the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your BIOS settings, in the System Configuration tab, enable virtualization technology.

Answer (score 0):

it seems i meet the same issue as which you mentioned above. but i did not get any prompt notification for the system image downloading, should i download the image manually? what system image need to be downloaded? could you share? thanks!

Comment: I downloaded the ARM 64 v8a System Image through the external SDK Manager, and then opened the AVD Manager in Android Studio, then on the virtual device listed there, there should be a "download image" link. Click that and it should download any remaining files and the device should work.

Comment: THANKS! but i found that it is not sys image relate issue, it is HAXM not be installed successfully, i re installed and re configed as the my new answer, it works now